# Tooltip bug in Kendo UI MVC Wrappers?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

**Issue**:

Occurs when we have a Kendo Tabstrip widget and the Kendo tooltip widgets within any of the tabs. When mousing over the tooltip activator, we get the following error message:

**Error**:

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: autoHide is not defined VM3349:3
    (anonymous function)VM3349:3
    a.extend._initPopupkendo.all.min.js:15
    a.extend._showkendo.all.min.js:15
    (anonymous function)
```

Here is the anonymous function where the error occurs:

```
(function(data
/**/) {
var o,e=kendo.htmlEncode;o='<div role="tooltip" class="k-widget k-tooltip';if (!autoHide) {;o+=' k-tooltip-closable';};o+='">';if (!autoHide) {;o+=' <div class="k-tooltip-button"><a href="#" class="k-icon k-i-close">close</a></div> ';};o+='<div class="k-tooltip-content"></div>';if (callout){ ;o+='<div class="k-callout k-callout-'+(dir)+'"></div>';};o+='</div>';return o;
})
```

**More**:

What may be interesting to note is that we are also using many other Kendo widgets within the tabstrip (e.g. calendar), and all widgets render and function correctly, except the tooltip widget.

Finally, all of which our Kendo MVC widget scripts are being Deferred. Here is a basic example of how we set things up:

```
<script  src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  src="kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script  src="kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>

<script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>

@Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts(True)
```

Any thoughts or possible known workarounds?

Using v2014.1.318

**Update**:

We have done further tests and it appears that simply rendering a tooltip (using MVC wrapper or Kendo UI Web) with requirejs causes the error described. This appears to be a bug and possibly a scope issue with the referenced "autoHide" variable used internally within Kendo's tooltip widget.

Comment: It looks like you're loading the scripts 2 times... That may be part of the problem

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? We are currently handling the full minified files outside of requirejs. We are not reloading these minified files through requirejs.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the `@Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts(true)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tooltips example where Kendo is loaded with RequireJS: http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@mishoo/ikAt/2

All seems fine to me.  I'm not sure what you mean by *“rendering a tooltip (using MVC wrapper or Kendo UI Web) with requirejs”* but perhaps if you paste the HTML as rendered in your browser (use View Source) we can figure it out.